# I want to save an existing List<T> into an XML file in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-serialization

I had a place class define as follow:

```
    public class place
    {
            public string placeID { get; set; }
            public string placeCatID { get; set; }
            public string placeName { get; set; }
    }
```

And the data store in a list call placelist

```
    List<place> placelist = new List<place>();
```

Can guide me how to convert the placelist to a string or export it and save it into an XML file format as follow:

```
    <place>
            <pID>0001</pID>
            <pCatID>C1</pID>
            <pName>Location 1</pName>
    </place>
    <place>
            <pID>0002</pID>
            <pCatID>C1</pID>
            <pName>Location 2</pName>
    </place>
```

Language using is C#

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, following options are availiable:

- How to: Serialize Using DataContractSerializer (C#): [DataContractSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-serialize-using-datacontractserializer)
- [LINQ to XML (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml)
- You may also benefit from [Examples of XML Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You can use any serializer that serializes to XML.  I would suggest DataContractSerializer

From MSDN:

```
DataContractSerializer s = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open("test" + typeof(T).Name + ".xml", FileMode.Create))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Testing for type: {0}", typeof(T)); 
        s.WriteObject(fs, obj);
    }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675198.aspx

In your case replace T with `List<T>`

Comment: Remember that DataContract and DataMember attributes should be added if you want to use DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 2):

Solution below is for `XmlSerializer` but you may use `DataContractSerializer` as well.
`XmlSerializer` serializes all the fields by default and with `DataContractSerializer` you need explicitly specify what is to be serialized.

Add Serialization attributes to have custom element names:

```
public class place
{
    [XmlElement("pID")]
    public string placeID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("pCatID")]
    public string placeCatID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("pName")]
    public string placeName { get; set; }
}
```

Code for serialization:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<place>));
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\1.xml");
// o is List<place> here
ser.Serialize(writer, o);
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfPlace xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <place>
    <pID>1</pID>
    <pCatID>2</pCatID>
    <pName>3</pName>
  </place>
  <place>
    <pID>3</pID>
    <pCatID>4</pCatID>
    <pName>5</pName>
  </place>
</ArrayOfPlace>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either write your own `ToXml()` method or use the `DataContractSerializer`.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote [a blog post on saving an object's data to Binary, XML, or Json](http://blog.danskingdom.com/saving-and-loading-a-c-objects-data-to-an-xml-json-or-binary-file/). Because you want your class variables to have a different name in the xml file than they do in code, you will need to decorate each public property with [XmlElement("NameToShowUpInXmlFileGoesHere")].

Once you have that, just call the following functions to save and load your object instance to / from a file.

Note: this requires the System.Xml assembly to be included in your project.

```
/// <summary>
/// Writes the given object instance to an XML file.
/// <para>Only Public properties and variables will be written to the file. These can be any type though, even other classes.</para>
/// <para>If there are public properties/variables that you do not want written to the file, decorate them with the [XmlIgnore] attribute.</para>
/// <para>Object type must have a parameterless constructor.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of object being written to the file.</typeparam>
/// <param name="filePath">The file path to write the object instance to.</param>
/// <param name="objectToWrite">The object instance to write to the file.</param>
/// <param name="append">If false the file will be overwritten if it already exists. If true the contents will be appended to the file.</param>
public static void WriteToXmlFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false) where T : new()
{
    TextWriter writer = null;
    try
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, append);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, objectToWrite);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (writer != null)
            writer.Close();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Reads an object instance from an XML file.
/// <para>Object type must have a parameterless constructor.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of object to read from the file.</typeparam>
/// <param name="filePath">The file path to read the object instance from.</param>
/// <returns>Returns a new instance of the object read from the XML file.</returns>
public static T ReadFromXmlFile<T>(string filePath) where T : new()
{
    TextReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.Close();
    }
}
```

### Example

```
public class place
{
    [XmlElement("pID")]
    public string placeID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("pCatID")]
    public string placeCatID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("pName")]
    public string placeName { get; set; }
}

// To write the placeList variable contents to XML.
WriteToXmlFile<List<place>>("C:\places.txt", placeList);

// To read the xml file contents back into a variable.
List<place> placeList= ReadFromXmlFile<List<place>>("C:\places.txt");
```